# Ergodic action on unitary group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group. Assume that $\theta:G\to U_d$ is a group homomorphism where $U_d$ is a finite dimensional unitary group. Consider a action of $G$ on $U_d$ by $g.u:=\theta(g)u,$ $u\in U_d.$ Consider $U=\overline{\theta(G)}.$ Is it true that $G$ acts ergodically on $U$ where $U$ is equipped with the invariant probability measure of $U_d$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $U_d$ is connected, every subgroup proper of it had infinite index, so unless $U=U_d$ it must be a set of measure zero there, and the literal answer is "no".

On the other hand, the action of $G$ on $U$ is ergodic for the Haar measure of $U$.  Indeed, let $f\in L^1(U)$ be $G$-invariant (e.g. the characteristic function of a $G$-invariant set).  Then by the continuity of the action of $U$ on $L^1(U)$, $f$ is $U$-invariant, hence constant a.e.

Comment: ($U_d$ being connected, $U$ of finite index means $U=U_d$.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking "compact Lie group".

Comment: Not clear what you mean by saying that the literal answer is "no". Look at the action of $\mathbb Z$ on the unit circle (aka $SO(2)$) determined by an irrational rotation.

Comment: In your case the closure of the image is all of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$.

Comment: @Daniel. It is better you should make some comment like ``dumb question" when you are sure not because you ``feel" something. I am a beginner what is dumb to you may be nontrivial to me..

Comment: @A beginner mathmatician Please forgive me I think my use of the English language caused some confusion I meant it was a dumb question on my part and that is why I used the verb feel, I was just trying to confirm my understanding of the problem with the answerer, I also try to learn here so we are in the same boat, my apologies to you I have deleted the comment and maybe I should rephrased it once again here as "Could you explain why this doesn't contradict the [Weyl's ergodic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) on $R/ Z\cong  SO(2)$?

Comment: @Daniel your question is the same as the one by R W above, and the answer is the same: the action is only ergodic wrt the invariant probability measure of $U$.  When $U=U_d$, this happens to be there invariant measure of $U_d$.

Comment: Consider the case of a *rational* circle rotation: the map $x\mapsto x+\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  When $\alpha$ is irrational, it generates a dense subgroup and hence acts ergodically wrt the invariant measure on the circle.  But when $\ alpha=p/q$ is rational, it generates the finite subgroup $U=\frac1q\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$.  This subgroup has measure zero in the circle, so the action on $U$ is not ergodic for Lebesgue measure on the circle.  However, the action is ergodically for the discrete measure on the finite group $U$.

Comment: I think I get it now, I needed this concrete example to understand what you proved, this also helped me understand better the weyl's ergodic theorem and what I had read about the [rotation number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_number#Properties), they make a lot more of sense now.